# Data Binding não funciona

Tags: android, android-databinding

Estou tentando utilizar o [Data Binding](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/tools/data-binding/guide.html) no Android.

Para isto adicionei o classpath na aplicação:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0-beta3'
        classpath 'com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.0-rc4'
    }
}


apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.android.databinding'
```

Mas quando tento compilar ocorre o seguinte erro:

> Error:Unable to find method
>   'android.databinding.tool.LayoutXmlProcessor.(Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/databinding/tool/writer/JavaFileWriter;IZLandroid/databinding/tool/LayoutXmlProcessor$OriginalFileLookup;)V'.
>   Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
>
> - Gradle's
>     dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network
>     connection timeout.) Re-download dependencies
>     and sync project (requires network)
> - The state of a Gradle
>     build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may
>     solve this problem. Stop Gradle build
>     processes (requires restart)
> - Your project may be using a
>     third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in
>     the project or the version of Gradle requested by the
>     project.
>
> In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can
>   also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

Não sei se é realmente necessário adicionar estas informações, mas quando tento compilar apenas habilitando o databinding:

```
dataBinding {
        enabled true
    }
```

Ocorre o seguinte :

> Error:(23, 23) No resource type specified (at 'text' with value
>   '@{user.name}').

Alguém já utilizou este recurso com sucesso?

Answer (score 1):

Tente fazer isso:

```
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

Colocar = depois do enabled